# How to change an image when hover over text? (Strictly HTML, CSS and JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

When an (x) amount of images are located next to (x) different paragraphs, how do I change the image when to a different image entirely when hovering over different paragraphs, as seen on dart.dev by google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on exactly what the use case is, you can do this without Javascript.

In this snippet the paragraphs and the space for the image are within the same container and then when hovering over a paragraph its associated image is shown as a background image to its before pseudo element which is positioned at the (communal) image position.

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
} 
.container .image, .container p:hover::before {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .image {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container div.pwrapper {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;  
}

.container p:hover::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  background-image: var(--bg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; 
}
.container p:nth-child(1) {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/384.jpg);
}
.container p:nth-child(2) {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1024/384.jpg);
}
.container p:nth-child(3):hover {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1024/384.jpg);
}
.container p:nth-child(4) {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1024/384.jpg);
}
.container p:nth-child(5) {
  --bg: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1024/1024/384.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="pwrapper">
    <p>First paragraph Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Second paragraph Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Third paragraph Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
    <p>Fourth paragraph Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Fifth paragraph Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed done using javascript as evidenced by it not working when you turn off javascript. What you'll want to do is have an `img` tag and use the javascript `mouseover` event. You could do something like this:

```
let img = document.getElementById("img-1");
let link1 = document.getElementById("link-1");
link1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => img.src = 'img1.png');
let link2 = document.getElementById("link-2");
link2.addEventListener('mouseover', () => img.src = 'img2.png');

... (Might want to use a loop)
```